# Finding out the veth# interface of a docker container

Tags: docker

I have hundreds of containers in various software virtual switches. I would like to know if its possible to find out which vnet# belongs to which docker container. Right now, I am detecting that by watching syslog as each container gets created. In KVM, there is a command "virsh domiflist ", which is exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `iflink` of the container is the same as the `ifindex` of the `veth#`.

You can get the `iflink` of the container as follows:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash -c 'cat /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink'
```

Say, that results in `12`, then `grep` for that:

```
grep -l 12 /sys/class/net/veth*/ifindex
```

That will give a unique result, on my system:

```
/sys/class/net/veth11d4238/ifindex
```

Combine that in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(docker ps -q); do
    iflink=`docker exec -it $container bash -c 'cat /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink'`
    iflink=`echo $iflink|tr -d '\r'`
    veth=`grep -l $iflink /sys/class/net/veth*/ifindex`
    veth=`echo $veth|sed -e 's;^.*net/\(.*\)/ifindex$;\1;'`
    echo $container:$veth
done
```

The script was written to be easy to follow.

Sample run:

```
$ docker ps -q
c4d8096eff43
34ac6e9f1e6e
d5a2aa5f3de3

$ sudo ./vethfinder
c4d8096eff43:veth11d4238
34ac6e9f1e6e:veth7d52cd1
d5a2aa5f3de3:vethe46073d
```

Reference: https://forums.docker.com/t/relationship-between-interface-vethxxxxx-and-container/12872/20

Comment: Thank you, but it for some reason doesn't always work. I have 50 containers, and the script above would return 1 or 2 blanks. When I look at the iflink value for both containers, they are not +1 from the value obtained from inside the container.

Comment: This is a guess: It could be a timing issue. If containers are created too quickly after each other, then assigning the `iflink` values might get out of sync. The system might assign two consecutive `iflink` values to two containers, instead of alternating between the container and the system.

Comment: This is interesting, I create and run the containers in a for loop, the last container iflink is always very different. For example, the iflink from /sys/class/net/veth###/iflink returns 4205, but the container's /sys/class/eth0/iflink shows 4216

Comment: Beats me. I tried a few things: starting a bunch of containers, verified that `iflink` lines up nicely. Stopped a few containers and created a few new ones, verified that `iflink` still lines up nicely. I got 115 containers running and my highest `iflink` was 244. How do you get to 4216?

Comment: I also checked the post I got the information from. It states: "This can be found out by matching a container interface's `iflink` value with a host `veth` interface's ifindex value". My script uses `iflink` for both. Maybe try 'ifindex' for 'veth' ?

Comment: I'll try that. I think iflink goes up continuously as the docker daemon is running. So if you run container creation/deletion in a loop, the iflink just goes up continously

Comment: you are right, checking against veth/ifindex is a match to containers eth0/iflink. So the relationship is 1 to 1 and the increment to the container's /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink is not required at all

Comment: That's great! Sorry about me misreading the post in the docker forum. I tested it on my docker box and I've updated the post.

Comment: No, thank you! You have no idea how helpful your answer has been. Now I can launch as many containers as possible without waiting for veth detection!

Comment: Since many containers don't have a bash-shell ready, I've changed `bash` to `sh` in the first line of the for loop. Now it reads: iflink=`docker exec -it $container sh -c 'cat /sys/class/net/eth0/iflink'` This works fine in all my containers.

Comment: I can't seem to run this code. When I put it into docker-vethfinder.sh, make it an executable and `sudo sh docker-vethfinder.sh` I get "docker-vethfinder.sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")"

Comment: @Grumpyol'Bear Are you sure you copied the commands correctly? There's nothing on line 2 of the script. It should work equally well with bash and with sh.

Answer (score 3):

searches for all interfaces in containers.

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'); do
    iflink=`docker exec -it $container bash -c 'cat /sys/class/net/eth*/iflink'`
    for net in $iflink;do
        net=`echo $net|tr -d '\r'`
        veth=`grep -l $net /sys/class/net/veth*/ifindex`
        veth=`echo $veth|sed -e 's;^.*net/\(.*\)/ifindex$;\1;'`
        echo $container:$veth
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using a different method, which seem to work just fine:

```
[root@kh1 ~]# docker inspect 6d48e279c5b8 --format '{{.State.Pid}}'                                                                                                                                                                                                              
56316
[root@kh1 ~]# 
[root@kh1 ~]# ip netns identify 56316
ns-56316
[root@kh1 ~]# 
[root@kh1 ~]# ip netns list | grep ns-56316
ns-56316 (id: 6)
[root@kh1 ~]# 
[root@kh1 ~]# ip link show | grep -B1 "link-netnsid 6"
330: veth1ce76e2b@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cni0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether de:f8:ce:a2:85:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
```

Comment: I have created a [tool](https://github.com/maximih/cniguru) that does the steps above automatically. You can download the linux x86_64 binary from [here](https://github.com/maximih/cniguru/releases/download/0.1.0/cniguru_x86_64_0.1.0.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860936/find-out-which-network-interface-belongs-to-docker-container

There are examples of how one can fetch veth names for running docker containers without root access.

An example shell script can be found here: https://github.com/dicho-usp/dockerveth

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=$1
PID=$(docker inspect $NAME --format "{{.State.Pid}}")
while read iface id; do
    [[ "$iface" == lo ]] && continue
    veth=$(ip -br addr | sed -nre "s/(veth.*)@if$id.*/\1/p")
    echo -e "$NAME\t$iface\t$veth"
done < <(</proc/$PID/net/igmp awk '/^[0-9]+/{print $2 " " $1;}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).